# Can I return HTTP response directly from Interceptor without server?

Tags: angular

I'm working on a sample project, that shows some info about `httpRequest` like: `queryParams`, `link`, `username`, ..etc.

I'm using `HttpInterceptor` to handle request and log these info.

So, I thought to use `HttpInterceptor` to return `HttpResponse` without complete request to server also, because all I need to deal with dummy data when using `get` or `post`, I don't need server APIs yet.

I that applicable? And how can I do that if yes?

Comment: If you are *mocking* the API calls, you can omit the interceptor itself. Just hard code the response in a service class and invoke it when you '*make*' the call.

Comment: As I mentioned, I need the Interceptor to log `HttpRequest` info, because my project supposed to do that, any ideas?

Comment: Hmm.. you can check if the request api matches the one you are looking to mock and then return the response from there. Also, (just curious here) where are you logging this info?

Comment: If you share a minimal setup of your code either in the question or via stackblitz, it would help even more.

Comment: @NicholasK check my answer below, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to return an `Observable` of `HttpResponse` without call `.handle` function,
like:

```
@Injectable()
export class NgxExampleLibService implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    // do something here

    return of(new HttpResponse({
      body: { msg: 'test' },
      status: 200
    }))

  }

  constructor() { }
}
```